# Calculating percentiles across certain rows in a data frame in r

Tags: r, rows, quantile

My data has a temperature measurement for each day in a year and other variables necessary for the analysis by villageID. I would like to create a new variable that calculates the 95 percentile threshold of all 365 temperature measurements for each village.

My data is in wide format and looks like this:

```
    villageID temp1 temp2 temp3.... temp365 otherVars
1         1    70    86    98        79         x
2         2    73    89    99        86         x
3         3    71    82    96        75         x
4         4    78    79    94        81         x
5         5    90    91    89        85         x
```

I would like to create this 95% threshold variable that calculates the threshold (or temperature measure) that indicates at what temperature the 95th percentile starts at. I would like to do this across all temperature measures columns[2:366] and keep all other variables the same.

Like this:

```
  villageID temp1 temp2 temp3 .....temp365 otherVars 95per
1         1    70    86    98        79         x      81
2         2    73    89    99        86         x      90
3         3    71    82    96        75         x      86
4         4    78    79    94        81         x      82
5         5    90    91    89        85         x      99
```

Comment: You would not choose to use `95per` since then you would need to always quote or backtick that column name. Perhaps `temp.95per` and I think you meant to say across all rows but only certain cols?

Answer (score 1):

Although I think you should keep your data in long format here is some code that will compute it and put it back in the wide format that you have. Just know that often times it's not the best way to go about things, especially if you want to plot your data later:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(~"villageID", ~"temp1", ~"temp2", ~"temp3", ~"temp365", 
             1,    70,    86,    98,        79, 
             2,    73,    89,    99,        86, 
             3,    71,    82,    96,        75, 
             4,    78,    79,    94,        81, 
             5,    90,    91,    89,        85) 

dat %>% 
  gather(key = "day", value = "temp", -villageID) %>% 
  group_by(villageID) %>% 
  mutate(perc_95 = quantile(temp, probs = .95)) %>% 
  spread(day, temp)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Groups:   villageID [5]
#>   villageID perc_95 temp1 temp2 temp3 temp365
#>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1         1    96.2    70    86    98      79
#> 2         2    97.5    73    89    99      86
#> 3         3    93.9    71    82    96      75
#> 4         4    92.0    78    79    94      81
#> 5         5    90.8    90    91    89      85
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In base R it would just be (assuming that only the temperature column have the string "temp" in them):

```
 dfrm$temp95perc <- 
            apply( dfrm[ ,grep("temp", names(dfrm) )], #select just `tempNNN` columns
                      1, # row-wise calcs
                            quantile, probs=0.95) # give `quantile` a probs
```